# How to play a video (.mp4) from assets or raw folder with the video intent?

Tags: android, file, video, android-intent, mp4

How can i play a mp4 video from my assets or raw folder with the video intent?

whatever i try i always get :

```
06-25 14:32:14.070: E/AndroidRuntime(3070): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.resource://mypackage/raw/myvideo }
```

I tryed:

```
   Intent tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

  String movieUrl = "file:///android_asset/myvideo.mp4";
  // String movieUrl = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + "myvideo.mp4";

   tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(movieUrl), "video/*");
   startActivity(tostart);
```

I can only find answers where people use video's from SD's card, is there any option so i can use the raw or assets folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse video Url from raw folder using this:

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://com.testvideo/" + R.raw.video);
```

then try:

Comment: @Luizje does it work? I have same problem. I am testing on LG G Pro android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Answer (score 1):

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd;

  try {
         afd = getAssets().openFd("videofile/video.3gp");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here **video.3gp** is file under folder --- **videofile** -> is one folder under assets folder

Using mediaplayer you can set this way

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();


 if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
   mediaPlayer.reset();
  }

  mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
  mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);

  try {
      mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd
                .getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());

   mediaPlayer.prepare();
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Any example for how to use the MediaPLayer?