# How to play video mp4 using intent from my android app? This is possible?

Tags: android, video, android-intent, mp4

I need to play a mp4 video in my app, bat I want to use intent. Is this possible?

```
private void startTrailer(){

            Uri contentUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + pkgName + "/" +R.raw.v01_homem_ferro_3);
    Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
    intent.setDataAndType( contentUri, "video/mp4" );
    context.startActivity( intent );
}
```

Exception: No Activity found to handle Intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody had this issue before. Check these links and see if they give you a good starting point to solve the problem:

[Android intent for playing video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572107/android-intent-for-playing-video?rq=1)

[How to play a video (.mp4) from assets or raw folder with the video intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189631/how-to-play-a-video-mp4-from-assets-or-raw-folder-with-the-video-intent)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, Here strMyVideo is my filepath,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strMyVideo));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(strMyVideo), "video/mp4");
activity.startActivity(intent);
```