# playing video in android device with the player of the device

Tags: android, video, device

I have an application that it can play video from the web service. it is like you tube application.
I don't want to use the object video View of android. 
I use the player of the device to play the video.
now i want, when the user download and install my application, the device of player for example km player, install with it

how can i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play video mp4 using intent from my android app? This is possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476781/how-to-play-video-mp4-using-intent-from-my-android-app-this-is-possible)

Comment: I want to install codec with my applications. I see this question were asked before. but with no answer